# job conf.xml parameter pig.mapPlan

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

Can we extract the map plan from the job conf.xml in a human readable format? What is the encoding used?

For example in the one of the conf file I see lines as follows(truncated due to character constraint).

```
<property>
  <name>
    pig.mapPlan
  </name>
  <value>
    kmonaaafhdhcaaeogphcghcogbhagbgdgigfcohagjghcogc
  </value>
</property>
```

[Edit] : This is for some  post execution analysis , hence getting the plan by using EXPLAIN is not of much help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pig.mapPlan` stores the physical plan of the job. It is serialized to a Base64 string.
To get back the PhysicalPlan object you can do the following:

```
import org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.plans.PhysicalPlan;
import org.apache.pig.impl.util.ObjectSerializer;
...

String pigMapPlan = "kmonaaafhdhcaaeogphcghcogbhagbgdgigfcohagjghcogc...";
PhysicalPlan plan = (PhysicalPlan) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(pigMapPlan);
...
System.out.println(plan); //does an explain on the plan
```

Comment: getting the stack trace java.util.zip.ZipException: incorrect header check
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2307)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2320)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2791)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:798)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:298)
at org.apache.pig.impl.util.ObjectSerializer.deserialize(Objec

Comment: if ("pig.mapPlan".equalsIgnoreCase(key)){
    pigMapPlan = value;
    PhysicalPlan plan = (PhysicalPlan) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(pigMapPlan);
    System.out.println(plan);
  }

Comment: imports are import org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.plans.PhysicalPlan;
import org.apache.pig.impl.util.ObjectSerializer;

Comment: Could you post the last part of the stack trace? Which Pig do you use? Make sure that you deserialize the string with the same Pig version you used for the encoding.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `EXPLAIN` command.  This will give you detailed information about the map-reduce plan for a given alias.